# Getting the address of a variable initialized in the data section

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, memory-address

I have started understanding assembly language. I tried to understand the memory layout and addressing of variables in data section and wrote the following code

```
mov bx,char1  ;copies the address to register bx

mov ah,0Eh

mov al,bh       ;moves the higher bit to al

add al,65       ;added 65 to al to see a recognizable asci character on screen

int 10h         ;print statement 1

mov al,bl       ;moves the lower bit to al

add al,50

int 10h         ;**print statement 2**


;**section 2 start**

mov bx,char2

;**section 2 end**


jmp $

char1: db "X"
char2: db "Y"

times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

As far I understand, char1 points to a byte in memory and char2 points to the very next byte. But I don't know why the presence of section 2 is affecting the character printed by  print statement 2. I have tested this in QEMU in a 64-bit platform. Can somebody please help me overcome this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Because your data comes after the code so if you increase code size your data will move accordingly.

Comment: You're printing the address, not the data, and that depends on everything before it.  Look at disassembly or a listing.  (`nasm -fbin -l /dev/stdout  foo.asm`)

Comment: @PeterCordes yeah, almost got it. Did you mean, even code instructions would be stored in the memory some where and that would effect the address of variables initialized in data segment?

Comment: Yeah, of course.  CPUs run instructions from memory; that's what makes them *programmable*.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored-program_computer).  `add al,65` emits 2 bytes into the output at that position, exactly the same 2 bytes as `db 0x04, 0x41` would.  Look at the listing. The whole 512-byte MBR boot sector gets loaded into memory at linear address `0x7C00`, then the BIOS jumps to that address.  It's up to you how much of that you use for machine code vs. data, but execution starts at the top of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> addressing of variables in **data section**

I believe your confusion stems from this idea that your variables are in a separate 'data' section.

Many assemblers will allow you to organize the program in multiple sections like `.stack`, `.data`, and `.code`, and if you do that kind of programming, then the offset address of a data item would not change after inserting an extra instruction.

But your current bootsector code is much simpler. You are not using sections at all. Everything you write gets encoded right where it is.

The code that prints the address occupies 17 bytes.

In the abscense of the 'section 2 instruction', the address of the *char1* variable would be 19. That's 17 plus the 2 bytes comming from the `jmp $` instruction.

By inserting the 'section 2 instruction', the address of the *char1* variable became 22. That's 17 **plus the 3 bytes coming from `mov bx, char2`** plus the 2 bytes coming from the `jmp $` instruction.

ps I'm assuming nothing comes before the printing code...